# Executing a click function after redirecting the person to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is the code that i tried below:
How do you execute the click function right after redirecting the person to another page using javascript

Home page html:

```
<a class="whitelink" href="#" onclick="redirectcontact()">Contact Us</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function redirectcontact()
{
    window.location="about.php#"; //From home page to redirect to about.php
    document.getElementById("clickcontact").click(); //command to execute when on about.php
    
}
```

Comment: After redirect your script loading again, so  `document.getElementById("clickcontact").click()` won't be executed.

Comment: You have to put the script `document.getElementById("clickcontact").click();` inside the about.php page

Comment: While the other comments are correct, what you are doing doesn't seem to follow any good practice in the first place. Why would you redirect and simulate a click on a contact link?

Comment: ok as theres 3 subpages in a page , About , contact us and faq and when I click on one of them the others that I did not click will do display:none while the one that i click will do display:block

Comment: Is there any other way that I can do this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After redirect your script loading again, so `document.getElementById("clickcontact").click()` won't be executed.

One of the solutions is to save varible in local storage or cookies

Here is example

Main page:

```
function redirectcontact()
{
      window.location="about.php#"; //From home page to redirect to about.php
      window.localStorage.setItem('click',true);

}
```

About.php

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
      if(window.localStorage.getItem('click')) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem('click');
            document.getElementById("clickcontact").click();
      }
})
```

Comment: But it doesn't work when I add another function redirectfaq() which redirects them to the same page but clicks on document.getElemebtById("clickfaq").click

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line on the script inside `about.php`

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
      // you can add that line here document.getElementById("clickcontact").click();
})
```

Comment: Thanks yours works too but adding a localstorage.removeItem after link is clicked works better for me as it does not always redirect me to that specific part of the page when I click another link which is suppose to bring me to the main part of the page

Answer (score 0):

But for the most part my second function, redirectfaq() doesn't work

About.php

```
 function redirectcontact()
        {
             window.location="about.php#";
          window.localStorage.setItem('click',true);
        }
function redirectfaq()
        {
             window.location="about.php#";
          window.localStorage.setItem('click2',true);
        }
        
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
           
              
             if(window.localStorage.getItem('click')) {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('click');
                    document.getElementById("clickcontact").click();
              }
 if(window.localStorage.getItem('click2')) {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('click2');
                    document.getElementById("clickfaq").click();
              }
        });
```

index.html

```
 <li><a class="whitelink" id="clickcontact" onclick="redirectcontact()" href="about.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="whitelink" id="clickfaq" onclick="redirectfaq()" href="about.php">FAQ</a></li>
```